# How to create layout in Android to list TextViews horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to create layout which looks like this:

[image: showcase]

Name1, Something1, OtherThing and Name2 are TextViews (each one of them is clickable with different action) which are added do parent layout programmatically. Sometime there too much elements to fit in one line. Which layout as parent should I use to let TextViews be placed horizontally but with possibility to "break line"? Horizontal LinearLayout isn't working.

Comment: Please show your Java code.

Comment: what you mean with break line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout):

> FlowLayout is an layout that display its children in multiple rows
>   depending on their size.
>   [image]

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="STUFF"
          android:textSize="30dp"/>

       </LinearLayout>
       <com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout                            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
        >
        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Name1" />

        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Something1" />

        <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="OtherThing" />

         <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Name2" />

       </com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout>

           <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="MORE STUFF"
         android:textSize="30dp"/>

       </LinearLayout>


     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awesome :) Thank very much.

Comment: do you know how to add margin to inner views? I tried like this but it's not working:
 FlowLayout.MarginLayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.MarginLayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 params.setMargins(10, 0, 0, 0);
 myFlowLayout.addView(myInnerView, params);

Comment: no, I would like to add marginLeft to each of inner views. myInnerView is one of TextViews I'm adding to FlowLayout.

Comment: FlowLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 params.setMargins(5,0,0,0);
myInnerView.setLayoutParams(params);myFlowLayout.addView(myInnerView);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103694/discussion-between-fabio-venturi-pastor-and-user3626048).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="STUFF"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Something1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OtherThing" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name2" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MORE STUFF"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Fabio Venturi Pastor is great solution.